# How do I output each processing item to file?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} | Out-File -path $env:temp\AppXPackage.log
```

This performs the task that I want it to perform. However, the log file is blank.

I would like for the log file to contain both the errors, and log the individual operations.

Comment: Are you really sure that `Add-AppxPackage` produces any output? You could try the parameters `-Verbose`, `-PassThru` and `-Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular cmdlet, you could probably try redirecting other output streams (so not stdout) to the log file, and it might work. at the very worst you can do something like this:

```
Foreach-Object {
   try {
        Add-AppxPackage ... -ErrorAction Stop
        "$_ done" > success.log
    } catch {
        $_ > errors.log
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Add-AppxPackage`doesn't return anything, neither does it support `-PassThru` argument. However, you could push the `$_` object to the pipe from the `foreach` block:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |
    Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register 
    "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"; $_ } |
         Out-File -path $env:temp\AppXPackage.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other 2 answers mentioned, that cmdlet doesn't seem to give any output. Which leaves you with either `manual logging` or `redirection`. I just wanted to expand a bit on the other two to give you a couple options.

For redirection, you can do something like this:

```
.\my_script *>> myfile.log #appen all streams (output and errors) to a file
.\my_script >> output.log 2>> errors.log #send output to one file and error stream to another
```

For normal logging, take a look at `$error`, which will contain all the errors in your session. You could start your script with `$error.clear()`, manually log your output you want since the cmdlet doesn't have output and then end with `$error | out-file errors.log`